# Testing the presence of a navigation bar in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to find a way to test for the presence of a navigation bar. The navigation bar will most likely be created in a partial and then rendered on to each separate page that is needed.

How do i go about make a test for this?

```
 <%= link_to "App_Name", root_path, :class => 'brand' %>
 <ul class="nav">
<% if user_signed_in? %>
<li>
<%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method=>'delete') %>        
</li>
<% else %>
<li>
<%= link_to('Login', new_user_session_path)  %>  
</li>
<% end %>
<% if user_signed_in? %>
<li>
<%= link_to('Edit account', edit_user_registration_path) %>
</li>
<% else %>
<li>
<%= link_to('Sign up', new_user_registration_path)  %>
</li>
<% end %> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you post some sample HTML that would demonstrate how the navigation bar is structured and where it is on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using either [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara), or [webrat](https://github.com/brynary/webrat) if you wish, in conjunction with RSpec request specs to test HTML page elements.

With Capybara, which is my preference, you would write a request spec like the following:

```
describe "Navigation Requests Spec" do

  describe "Navigation should be available" do
    it "should show the navigation on the home page" do
      visit root_path
      page.should have_link('Logout')
      page.should have_link('Login')
      page.should have_link('Sign up')
    end
  end
end
```

Obviously you then add tests for logged users and check what they can see. I have put all the assertions into one test in this case to keep the answer shorter, you may want to break them out into separate test which is generally recommended as an RSpec approach although it's really your personal preference..

The capybara page is well worth checking out, it has significant capabilities to test all kinds of html on a page. It would be worth checking out the detail for RSpec request tests as well.

Answer (score 0):

I remember one similar question about RSpec with your one. Most things are simple, this is not an exception. Just check the HTML code generated, or "what you see" and tell RSpec to check for the presence of this element(s). Hope that helps,